# inserting multiple data into different tables using linq to entities?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, linq-to-entities

I'm using AdventureWorks sample database in a project.  I can display the Customer's (being various stores) information using vStorewithDemographics.  It's a view retrieving different pieces of data from different tables in database.

I want my program to insert a new customer into the database using linq to entities and I'm not sure how to go about this.  Inserting into the view just gives me errors, which I thought would happen because it's not a table.

Any way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible follow following steps

--> Create a instead of trigger and using it you can perform it
Eg, I have two table customer and customerContacts latter contain the phone number of customer and a view name customer details will bring upon all the details of customer as below

create view [dbo].[CustomerDetails] as
select c.*,cc.PhoneNumber from customer c inner join customerContact cc on c.CustomerId = cc.CustomerId

For inserting in have create a instead of trigger

Create TRIGGER trgInsteadOfUpdate ON dbo.CustomerDetails

INSTEAD OF INSERT

AS

Declare @Id int

-- Insert into Customer
INSERT INTO customer SELECT CustomerName,CustomerAddress,State,Country FROM inserted

Set @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- Insert into CustomerContact
INSERT INTO customerContact SELECT PhoneNumber,@Id FROm inserted

GO

When for inserting in the linq i can user any of the following two ways

//Insert into view

var newCusContact = new CustomerDetail{ Country="India", CustomerAddress="bbb", CustomerName="Tested", PhoneNumber="7879654", State="Delhi" };

db.CustomerDetails.InsertOnSubmit(newCusContact);

db.SubmitChanges();

OR

string insertStatement = "insert into CustomerDetails(CustomerName,CustomerAddress,State,Country,PhoneNumber) values('DummyValue','DummyValue','Delhi','India','123459')";

db.ExecuteQuery(insertStatement);

db.SubmitChanges();

Hope this helps you